# Suppose $f^2$ and $f^3$ are analytic in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. Is $f$ necessarily analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose $f^2$ and $f^3$ are analytic in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. Is $f$ necessarily analytic?

If we only assume that $f^2$ is analytic, then is $f$ necessarily analytic? I think there should be a counter example, but I am can not find one.

Comment: We can have $f(z)=1$ for all $z\in\Bbb Q+i\Bbb Q$ and $f(z)=-1$ otherwise. Then $f$ is not analytic, but $f^2$ is.

Comment: Think about $f^3/f^2$ and analyze the different possible cases of singularities.

Comment: By $f^2$ do you meant $f\cdot f$ or $f\circ f \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: By $f^2$ I mean $f \cdot f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_0\in\Omega$.

If $f(z_0)\ne 0$, then $f(z)=\frac{f^3(z)}{f^2(z)}$ is analytic at $z_0$.

If $f(z)$ is identically $0$ in a naeighbourhood of $z_0$, then clearly $f$ is analytic at $z_0$.

If $f(z_0)=0$ and $f$ is not identically $0$ in any neighbourhood of $z_0$,  then $f^2(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ and $f^3(z)=(z-z_0)^mh(z)$ with analytic functions $g,h$ not vanishing at $z_0$.
Then 
$$ 0=(f^2)^3-(f^3)^2=(z-z_0)^{3n}g^3(z)-(z-z_0)^{2m}h^3(z)$$
and we conclude $3n=2m$. Then $n=2k$ and $m=3k$ for some integer $k$ and we readily find $$\frac{f^3(z)}{f^2(z)}=(z-z_0)^k\frac{h(z)}{g(z)} $$
which again is analytic at $z_0$.